# Load all classes from a package with an @Path annotation

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I've tried search for answers, but haven't come up with anything. I want to leverage an existing JAR that has several classes under several parts of a package. These classes have JAX-RS annotations, so I was hoping to use CXF to load all of them and have them wired as CXF endpoints.

Is it possible with CXF to point it at a package and have it wire all the classes to endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `CXF` won't load some classes from some `jar` annotated with some annotation. You need to do this manually. For e.g. to get the classes annotated with specific annotation you can use this:

```
public class AnnotationHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnnotationHandler.class);

    /**
     * Scans all classes accessible from the context class loader which belong to the given package and sub packages.
     *
     * @param packageName the base package
     * @return The classes
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException if class not found exception occurs
     * @throws IOException            if IO error occurs
     */
    public Iterable<Class> getClasses(String packageName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
        Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
        LinkedList<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL resource = resources.nextElement();
            dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
        }
        LinkedList<Class> classes = new LinkedList<Class>();
        for (File directory : dirs) {
            classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
        }
        return classes;
    }

    /**
     * Recursive method used to find all classes in a given directory and sub directories.
     *
     * @param directory   the base directory
     * @param packageName the package name for classes found inside the base directory
     * @return the classes
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException if class not found exception occurrs
     */
    private LinkedList<Class> findClasses(File directory, String packageName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LinkedList<Class> classes = new LinkedList<Class>();
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            return classes;
        }
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    classes.addAll(findClasses(file, packageName + "." + file.getName()));
                } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    classes.add(Class.forName(
                            packageName + '.'
                                    + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6)));
                }
            }
        }
        return classes;
    }

    /**
     * Finds all classes annotated with passed annotation in provided package. Unchecked system exception might be
     * thrown if the class is not found or IO exception occurs.
     *
     * @param annotationClass annotation class
     * @param packageName     package name to search for annotated classes
     * @return list of annotated class with specified annotation
     */
    public LinkedList<Class> findAnnotatedClasses(Class annotationClass, String packageName) {
        LinkedList<Class> classes = new LinkedList<Class>();
        try {
            for (Class clazz : getClasses(packageName)) {
                if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)) {
                    classes.add(clazz);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Class not found exception occurred.", ex);
            throw new SystemException("Class not found exception occurred.", ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("IO exception occurred.", ex);
            throw new SystemException("IO exception occurred.", ex);
        }
        return classes;
    }

}
```

Call `findAnnotatedClasses` by providing annotation class and package name to look into and you will have a list of classes annotated with the specified annotation.

Then you can do what ever you want with those classes.

Comment: wow. Thank you for all that, it worked perfectly. I guess I was hoping for a CXF option, but in the absence this was what I had in mind.